# find only the group members in r

Tags: r

I'm stuck with defining group members to an individual. I was working in excel but that is failing since the number of individuals in a group varies between groups. I used this formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$10727;SMALL(IF($S$1:$S$10727=$S2;ROW($S$1:$S$10727);"");Nth);1);"NA")
```

This returns the Nth individual in a group. This is not working since gives me all the individuals and I only want the group member, so not the individuals itself. So I was thinking to go to R, but I don't know where to start.

My data looks like this:

```
group ID 
1     1
1     2
1     3
2     4
2     5
3     6
3     7
3     8
3     9
3     10
```

I would like this:

```
group ID gm1 gm2 gm3 gm4
1     1   2   3   NA  NA
1     2   1   3   NA  NA
1     3   1   2   NA  NA
2     4   5   NA  NA  NA  
2     5   4   NA  NA  NA  
3     6   7   8   9   10
3     7   6   8   9   10
3     8   6   7   9   10
3     9   6   7   8   10
3     10  6   7   8   9
```

Is there a formula in R that gives me the group members?

Comment: Your question isnt clear, why do we have gm4 when there is no group 4 in the data you posted.

Comment: gm stands for group member. group number 3 has 5 individuals in the group, so each individual has 4 group members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `combn` and `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
df1$gm <- unlist(unsplit(lapply(split(df1$ID, df1$group), function(x)
       lapply(x, function(y) {
           i1 <- x[y!= x]
         if(length(i1) >1) combn(i1, length(i1), FUN = paste, collapse=", ") else i1
          })), df1$group))
cSplit(df1, 'gm', ', ')
#    group ID gm_1 gm_2 gm_3 gm_4
# 1:     1  1    2    3   NA   NA
# 2:     1  2    1    3   NA   NA
# 3:     1  3    1    2   NA   NA
# 4:     2  4    5   NA   NA   NA
# 5:     2  5    4   NA   NA   NA
# 6:     3  6    7    8    9   10
# 7:     3  7    6    8    9   10
# 8:     3  8    6    7    9   10
# 9:     3  9    6    7    8   10
#10:     3 10    6    7    8    9
```

---

Or the same can be implemented with `data.table` and `cSplit`

```
library(data.table)
cSplit(setDT(df1)[,  gm := unlist(lapply(seq_len(.N), function(i) {
             i1 <- ID[i != seq_len(.N)]
          if(length(i1) > 1) combn(i1, length(i1), FUN =paste, collapse=", ") 
        else as.character(i1)})), group], 'gm', ', ')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), ID = 1:10), .Names = c("group", "ID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: This is not doing it yet. It returns the individual itself, but I need the group members

Comment: @Lisette Both the methods give the expected output you showed in your post.  If i quote your words `I would like this:`

Comment: I missed the edit :) However, I get errors in the first one `In [<-.data.table(x, j = name, value = value) :
  Supplied 28 items to be assigned to 10 items of column 'gm' (18 unused)`

Comment: And the second one: `Error in [.data.table(setDT(df), , :=(gm, unlist(lapply(seq_len(.N),  : 
  Type of RHS ('character') must match LHS ('integer'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself`

Seems something of the data frame itself? Can you share how you created the data frame?

Comment: @Lisette  This is based on the dataset you showed.  It is working for me

Comment: I don't know why it works now, but the cSplit does the trick with the larger dataset

Comment: @Lisette  May be youhad factor class variables ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` you could solve this in the following way. First we define a function that solves the problem for a single group, then we simply apply this function to all the groups using `do`.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(group = rep(1:3, c(3, 2, 5)), ID = 1:10)

add_group_members <- function(df) {
   df_copy <- df 
   colnames(df_copy)[2] <- "gm_id"
   inner_join(df, df_copy, by = c("group" = "group")) %>% 
   filter(ID != gm_id) %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(gm = paste("gm", row_number(), sep = '')) %>% 
   tidyr::spread(key = gm, value = gm_id) %>% ungroup
}

df %>% group_by(group) %>% do(add_group_members(.)) %>% ungroup
```

Comment: Yep, you do, that's what I mentioned in the first line :)

Comment: Still need some help :( When I try it with my original dataset (about 10.000 individuals, I get the error; `Error: object 'group' not found`. It refers to the inner_join. There is no difference between the datasets, except for the number of observations and the length of the values (both 9 digits long)

Comment: I guess your column is not named group in your real data... Replace it by the actual column name

Answer (score 0):

Another `tidyverse` solution:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:3, c(3, 2, 5)), id = 1:10)

library(tidyverse)
df2 <-
  df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(unique = paste(unique(id), collapse = ","))

df2$group_unique <- map_chr(seq_len(nrow(df2)), function(index) {
  row_unique <- as.numeric(strsplit(df2[[index, "unique"]], ",")[[1]])
  paste0(setdiff(row_unique, df2[[index, "id"]]), collapse = ",")
})

df2 %>%
  select(-unique) %>%
  separate(group_unique, paste("gm_", 1:(max(table(df$x)) - 1)))
```

Comment: Works on the small data set, but my data set is large, which results in the following error: `Error in 1:(max(table(df$x)) - 1) : result would be too long a vector`